# What is difference between x,y = y,y+x and x=y , y=x+y?

Tags: python, variable-assignment, fibonacci

I've just written these codes but outputs are different. second code's output is correct that I expected, but the first code's output is incorrect. but why?

```
def fib(n):
    x = 0
    y = 1
    print x
    for i in range(n):
        x = y
        y = x+y
        print x
    return x
```

output is; when n = 5

```
0
1
2
4
8
16


def fib(n):
    x,y = 0,1
    print x
    for i in range(n):
        x,y = y,x+y
        print x
    return x
```

output is; when n = 5

```
0
1
1
2
3
5
```

second code is correct but,
`x,y = y,x+y` and 
`x = y , y = x+y` 
they look like same but outputs are different why?

Comment: In your latter case `y` doesn't get updated on the right hand side, both `x` and `y` will be assigned based on the _old_ value of `y`. A tuple `(y,x+y)` is constructed using the old value of `y`, then this tuple is unpacked as the new values of `x` and `y` on the left-hand side. In the first case `x` gets updated by the time you try to compute `y` so you get the wrong result.

Comment: You'll need a temporary variable for the old value of `x`, like in most languages. In python I'd use the second one, it's more elegant and cleaner :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They give different outputs because with x=y, then y=x+y, you are setting x to the value of y. Then you take x, once its value has been updated and add it to y to find the y variable. With the one line variable declaration (x,y=y,y+x) in the y = y+x part of the equation, it will use a previous value of x instead of what you set it to in that line.

If you had:

```
x=0
y=1
```

Then you tried the one line declaration, it would look like this:

```
x,y=1,0+1
x,y=y,x+y
```

I hope this helped :)

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that you will update x and then use it in the first example and you will directly use it in the second example.

```
x, y = 0, 1
x = y     # after this line x will be 1
y = x + y   # y = 1 + 1
```

Second example

```
x,y = 0, 1
x,y = y,x+y  # x, y = (1, 0 + 1) the old value of x will be used
```

This is because it will first generate the tuple on the right-hand side and after that, the tuple in your case `(1, 1)` will be assigned to `x` and `y`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go without tuple, you'll have to assign the value of x to a new variable z before updating it with the value of y and use this new variable to calculate the value of y.
The code is from a different problem, but the output is a Fibonacci sequence.

```
    x = 0
    y = 1
    print(x)
    while y < 50:
        print(y)
        z = x
        x = y
        y = z+y
```